# CakePHP scriptBlock is not adding any JavaScript in HTML page

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-3.8

I just want to add below mention JavaScript within an HTML `<script>` Tag.

But below mentioned CakePHP 3.8 `scriptBlock` function is not creating any element on my HTML page.

```
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('
    $.get("/feed.rss", function(data) {
        var $XML = $(data);
        var active=" active";
        $XML.find("item").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                item = {
                    title:       $this.find("title").text(),
                    link:        $this.find("link").text(),
                    description: $this.find("description").text(),
                    pubDate:     $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                    author:      $this.find("author").text()
                };
            $(".carousel-inner").append("<div class=\"carousel-item" + active + "\"><h2>" + item.title + "</h2>" + item.description + "</div>");
            active = "";
        });
    });
    $(".carousel").carousel();',
    
    ['buffer' => true]
);
```

Please tell me what should I do?

Comment: try `echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(...`

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-inline-javascript-blocks

Comment: Now it is working, When I replaced `['buffer' => true]`  with  `['block' => true]`.

Comment: options are block and safe. https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.View.Helper.HtmlHelper.html#553-588.  https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Helper.HtmlHelper.html#_scriptBlock

Comment: Thanks @Salines, But I have multiple `scriptBlock` in my code and want all in one single `<script>` tag. The current change is creating separate Tags for each.